# Scala - tracking mathematical function dependent variables - Ident error

Tags: scala

I have a query regarding Scala. I am attempting to write a function tracking the dependencies of a mathematical function e.g `f(x) = t or f(x) = x`.

I have made a lot of progress except the final hurdle - the `f(x) = x` case. When this test runs, it reaches the Ident case (Java.universe.IdentExtractor) and subsequently runs `ns.get(i)` where `i` is the current tree `("x")` and `ns` is a `Map$Map1` with TermName f and Ident "x". I want the `ns.get(i)` to return some(exp) since the "x" is in the Map. However, it keeps returning None.

I believe it is only checking the TermName and not the TermName and Ident. How do I fix this? 
I cannot use contains as this causes a number of other tests to fail.

Comment: Would you mind using the wonderful Markdown capabilities provided by stackoverflow to make your question more readable ? - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you share some of the code? Hard to understand what you mean without the code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I couldn't share my code for legal reasons but managed to fix the issue. Was a tiny error in the middle of my code that I had missed.